# Postgres array of Golang structs

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I have the following Go struct:

```golang
type Bar struct {
    Stuff string `db:"stuff"`
    Other string `db:"other"`
}

type Foo struct {
    ID    int    `db:"id"`
    Bars  []*Bar `db:"bars"`
}
```

So `Foo` contains a slice of `Bar` pointers. I also have the following tables in Postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id  INT
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
    id      INT,
    stuff   VARCHAR,
    other   VARCHAR,
    trash   VARCHAR
)
```

I want to `LEFT JOIN` on table `bar` and aggregate it as an array to be stored in the struct `Foo`. I've tried:

```sql
SELECT f.*,
ARRAY_AGG(b.stuff, b.other) AS bars
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.id = b.id
WHERE f.id = $1
GROUP BY f.id
```

But it looks like the `ARRAY_AGG` function signature is incorrect (`function array_agg(character varying, character varying) does not exist`). Is there a way to do this without making a separate query to `bar`?

Comment: Add the code how you bind your data in struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.4.2.2.1.1.1) takes a *single* argument and returns an array of the type of the argument. So, if you want all of a row's columns to be included in the array's elements you can just pass in the row reference directly, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(b) FROM b
```

If, however, you only want to include specific columns in the array's elements you can use the [`ROW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) constructor, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(ROW(b.stuff, b.other)) FROM b
```

---

Go's standard library provides out-of-the-box support for scanning only scalar values. For scanning more complex values like arbitrary objects and arrays one has to either look for 3rd party solutions, or implement their own [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner).

To be able to implement your own `sql.Scanner` and properly parse a postgres array of rows you first need to know what format postgres uses to output the value, you can find this out by using `psql` and some queries directly:

```sql
-- simple values
SELECT ARRAY[ROW(123,'foo'),ROW(456,'bar')];
-- output: {"(123,foo)","(456,bar)"}

-- not so simple values 
SELECT ARRAY[ROW(1,'a b'),ROW(2,'a,b'),ROW(3,'a",b'),ROW(4,'(a,b)'),ROW(5,'"','""')];
-- output: {"(1,\"a b\")","(2,\"a,b\")","(3,\"a\"\",b\")","(4,\"(a,b)\")","(5,\"\"\"\",\"\"\"\"\"\")"}
```

As you can see this can get pretty hairy but nevertheless it's parseable, the syntax looks to be something like this:

```
{"(column_value[, ...])"[, ...]}
```

where `column_value` is either an unquoted value, or a quoted value with escaped double quotes, and such a quoted value itself *can* contain escaped double quotes but only in twos, i.e. a single escaped double quote will not occur inside the `column_value`. So a rough and incomplete implementation of the parser might look something like this:

**NOTE: there may be other syntax rules, that I do not know of, that need to be taken into consideration during parsing. In addition to that the code below doesn't handle NULLs properly.**

```golang
func parseRowArray(a []byte) (out [][]string) {
    a = a[1 : len(a)-1] // drop surrounding curlies

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] == '"' { // start of row element
            row := []string{}

            i += 2 // skip over current '"' and the following '('
            for j := i; j < len(a); j++ {
                if a[j] == '\\' && a[j+1] == '"' { // start of quoted column value
                    var col string // column value

                    j += 2 // skip over current '\' and following '"'
                    for k := j; k < len(a); k++ {
                        if a[k] == '\\' && a[k+1] == '"' { // end of quoted column, maybe
                            if a[k+2] == '\\' && a[k+3] == '"' { // nope, just escaped quote
                                col += string(a[j:k]) + `"`
                                k += 3    // skip over `\"\` (the k++ in the for statement will skip over the `"`)
                                j = k + 1 // skip over `\"\"`
                                continue  // go to k loop
                            } else { // yes, end of quoted column
                                col += string(a[j:k])
                                row = append(row, col)
                                j = k + 2 // skip over `\"`
                                break     // go back to j loop
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if a[j] == ')' { // row end
                        out = append(out, row)
                        i = j + 1 // advance i to j's position and skip the potential ','
                        break     // go to back i loop
                    }
                } else { // assume non quoted column value
                    for k := j; k < len(a); k++ {
                        if a[k] == ',' || a[k] == ')' { // column value end
                            col := string(a[j:k])
                            row = append(row, col)
                            j = k // advance j to k's position
                            break // go back to j loop
                        }
                    }

                    if a[j] == ')' { // row end
                        out = append(out, row)
                        i = j + 1 // advance i to j's position and skip the potential ','
                        break     // go to back i loop
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Try it on [`playground`](https://play.golang.org/p/9xKLn8hteoJ).

With something like that you can then implement an `sql.Scanner` for your Go slice of bars.

```golang
type BarList []*Bar

func (ls *BarList) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch data := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        a := praseRowArray(data)
        res := make(BarList, len(a))
        for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
            bar := new(Bar)
            // Here i'm assuming the parser produced a slice of at least two
            // strings, if there are cases where this may not be the true you
            // should add proper length checks to avoid unnecessary panics.
            bar.Stuff = a[i][0]
            bar.Other = a[i][1]
            res[i] = bar
        }
        *ls = res
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now if you change the type of the `Bars` field in the `Foo` type from `[]*Bar` to `BarList` you'll be able to directly pass in a pointer of the field to a `(*sql.Row|*sql.Rows).Scan` call:

```golang
rows.Scan(&f.Bars)
```

If you don't want to change the field's type you can still make it work by converting the pointer just when it's being passed to the `Scan` method:

```golang
rows.Scan((*BarList)(&f.Bars))
```

---

#### JSON

An `sql.Scanner` implementation for the json solution suggested by Henry Woody would look something like this:

```golang
type BarList []*Bar

func (ls *BarList) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if b, ok := src.([]byte); ok {
        return json.Unmarshal(b, ls)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like what you want is for `bars` to be an array of bar objects to match your Go types. To do this, you should use `JSON_AGG` rather than `ARRAY_AGG` since `ARRAY_AGG` only works on single columns and would produce in this case an array of type text (`TEXT[]`). `JSON_AGG`, on the other hand, creates an array of json objects. You can combine this with `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` to select only the columns you want.

Here's an example:

```sql
SELECT f.*,
JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('stuff', b.stuff, 'other', b.other)) AS bars
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.id = b.id
WHERE f.id = $1
GROUP BY f.id
```

Then you'll have to handle unmarshaling the json in Go, but other than that you should be good to go.

Note also that Go will ignore unused keys for you when unmarshaling json to a struct, so you can simplify the query by just selecting all fields on the `bar` table if you want. Like so:

```sql
SELECT f.*,
JSON_AGG(TO_JSON(b.*)) AS bars -- or JSON_AGG(b.*)
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.id = b.id
WHERE f.id = $1
GROUP BY f.id
```

If you want to also handle cases where there are no entries in `bar` for a record in `foo`, you can use:

```sql
SELECT f.*,
COALESCE(
    JSON_AGG(TO_JSON(b.*)) FILTER (WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL),
    '[]'::JSON
) AS bars
FROM foo f
LEFT JOIN bar b
ON f.id = b.id
WHERE f.id = $1
GROUP BY f.id
```

Without the `FILTER`, you'll get `[NULL]` for rows in `foo` that have no corresponding rows in `bar`, and the `FILTER` gives you just `NULL` instead, then just use `COALESCE` to convert to an empty json array.